# socket_recvfrom() goes stuck in ubuntu server

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I'm using the `socket_recvfrom()` function for getting data form a device

```
socket_recvfrom($this->socket, $this->received_data, 1024, 0, $this->ip, $this->port);
```

This works perfectly for a valid IP and port, if I changed to wrong IP it goes stuck and the process does not end. How can I skip from this line of code if it is an invalid IP? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (filter_var($this->ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
    socket_recvfrom($this->socket, $this->received_data, 1024, 0, $this->ip, $this->port);
}
```

for more details check these links
[PHP FILTER_VALIDATE_IP Filter](https://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_ip.asp) & [Filter flags](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php)

Comment: sorry the function is going stuck not only if it is not a valid ip,it stucks due to some other reasons like the device(of given ip) is not connected through internet or the device is turned off.